# Finding invalid data row number while reading csv

Tags: c#, csv

My csv file strcture is:

```
int      | only numbers  
string   | only characters 
string   | only characters 
int      | only numbers  
char     | only a character
```

suppose one of row in csv file has invalid data-not matching with decided datatype.
For example:

```
27      | Patrick     | 777         | 32       | Male
```

Then i want the invalid row number- row#27 in this case.

Please help.

Comment: how are you reading your file?

Comment: How is your example row invalid? Are you saying that you want the second string to only have alphabetic characters in it? i.e. no numbers at all.

Comment: can you show code that you tried? also do you need c-sharp solution or tools?

Comment: @ZacBraddy yes! Only aphabets! 1st two strings are name and surname.

Comment: @Bulat No tool ! Any help by code which will give invalid data row number while reading file will be appreciating !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helper methods:

```
bool ContainsOnlyNumbers( string input )
{
  // beginning of string, one or more digits, end of string
  return Regex.IsMatch( input, @"^\d+$" );
}

bool ContainsOnlyLetters( string input )
{
  // beginning of string, one or more letters, end of string
  return Regex.IsMatch( input, @"^[A-Za-z]+$" );
}
```

You need to consider whether you allow spaces - you may want to call .Trim on your strings.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that comes to my mind is this:

```
List<int> invalidRows;
int currentRow = 0;

 var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(myfile));
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(';');
        if(rowHasErrors(values))
            invalidRows.Add(currentRow);
        currentRow++;
    }
```

you would have to write a function to check if row has errors of course

Comment: how do you know the line are separated by a `;`

Comment: i don't. and not lines, but values in the line. i hope OP would know what they are separated with and make needed adjustments